# Problema mikronodecon logueo desde el api de Mikronode

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de conectarme a mi enrutador por medio del api de mikronode, hace la interacción, pero no puedo pasar más de ahi, los datos de acceso son correctos, pero en la terminal me dice que el logueo ha fallado: (login failure for user api from 192.168.x.xx via api). ¿A alguien le ha pasado?

```
// Importar MikroNode
const MikroNode = require('mikronode');

// Definir la IP, el nombre de usuario y la contraseña
const ip = '192.168.2.1';
const username = 'admin';
const password = 'password';

// Crear una conexión
const device = new MikroNode(ip);

device.connect()
.then(([login]) => login(username, password))
.then(conn => {
    // Abrir un canal
    const chan = conn.openChannel();

    // Escribir un comando en el canal
    chan.write('/ip/address/print');

    // Escuchar el evento 'done'
    chan.on('done', data => {
        const parsed = MikroNode.parseItems(data);
        parsed.forEach(item => {
            console.log('Interface/IP: ' + item.interface + '/' + item.address);
        });

        // Cerrar el canal
        chan.close();
    });
})
.catch(error => console.log('Error:', error));
```